# function templates dealing with values and pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, smart-pointers

If I have a function template that has a template parameter by value or ref like

```
template<class T> void DoSomething(T& t){ t.method();}
```

if i want to deal with pointers or smart pointers is it best derefernce first so the code works or write a delegating function like

```
template<class T> void DoSomething(T* t){ Dosomething(*t);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all "is it best" questions, the answer is "it depends". There will be debates and opinions.

However, I would recommend using the second method. The reason is that, you can then add extra checks in the second form of the function. For example:

```
template<class T> void DoSomething(T* t)
{
    if (t == NULL)
        give_error_somewhere();
    else
        Dosomething(*t);
}
```

But like I said, it most certainly depends on your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your project. As for me, i'd use the first variant. Here are some reasons:

1. If we pass pointer, we should keep in mind that it can be NULL. But should this function be responsible for validity of the supplied parameter? If function is a tool, it should work with value, the validness of the parameter is not of it's concern. I think i'd use second variant only if i needed explicitly say that function accepts value or nothing. If your function expects only value, then why would you burden it with additional checks?
2. You can always pass dereferenced pointer, and if you use any smart pointer, you don't care about what to do if stored pointer is NULL, because all standard smart pointers will throw exception if you try to dereference NULL pointer.

Comment: Even though your argument is valid, it's not what the OP is asking. He already has the first method. His question is whether to "add another function taking pointers" or leave the dereferencing to the user. Hence the term "delegating function"